# How can I find a path to the Chrome plugin elements?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I would like to write an automation test by using Selenium + IntelliJ Idea or Ranorex Studio and I can't find those elements. I can find a parent container and that's all. Is there any good idea of how I can do that?

I tried AutoIT, Ranorex Studio and Inspect from Windows Kit.

I expect that I will be able to find any of the included elements in the container (parent container with all elements inside) and I will be able to click on each element.

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or C#?

Comment: How is the question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.
1. I would like to use Selenium for the autotests (Java) or Ranorex Studio (C#).
2. If I use Selenium I can use AutoIT, Winium, etc. to determine some elements which are the Windows application. Because only with single Selenium I can't click on any elements inside the container which I mentioned earlier. 
Is my question clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the plugins and even dev tools with Ranorex but you need to first enable Accessibility in Chrome:

-Go to chrome://accessibility

-Turn global accessibility on

-consider adding it as an argument to the "Open Browser" action with the flag:

```
   --force-renderer-accesibility
```

[pic of Ranorex Spy tracking plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcu75.png)